# Android Programmatically add an ImageView on top of Another ImageView

Tags: java, android, grid-layout

So i'm trying to create a board game token, and place that token at it's starting point. Just so happens on this level it starts on top of ImageView onetwo. However when i create the token and tell it where to go it shows up under the gridview. Any ideas or help would be appreciated!

I guess its because i'm using RelativeLayout.ALIGN_TOP inside a grid view but i haven't see the alternative.

Java:

```
public void createToken(){
    // Let's create the missing ImageView
    ImageView image = new ImageView(this);

    // Now the layout parameters, these are a little tricky at first
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(75, 75);
    params.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_RIGHT, R.id.onetwo);
    params.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_LEFT, R.id.onetwo);
    params.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_TOP, R.id.onetwo);
    params.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_BOTTOM, R.id.onetwo);

    image.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_INSIDE);
    image.setImageResource(R.drawable.robo);

    // Let's get the root layout and add our ImageView
    GridLayout layout = (GridLayout) findViewById(R.id.gridLayout1);
    layout.addView(image, params);
}
```

XML:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:id="@+id/root" >

...

<GridLayout
    android:id="@+id/gridLayout1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:columnCount="3"
    android:rowCount="5" >

    ...

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/onetwo"
        android:layout_width="75dp"
        android:layout_height="75dp"
        android:layout_columnSpan="1"
        android:layout_rowSpan="1"
        android:contentDescription="@string/gameboard"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:src="@drawable/tile" />

    ...
</GridLayout>

...

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up creating an imageview programmatically and then placing it inside the relative layout below on top of the imageview:

```
<GridLayout
    android:id="@+id/gridLayout1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:columnCount="3"
    android:rowCount="5" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="75dp"
        android:layout_height="75dp"
        android:layout_columnSpan="1"
        android:layout_rowSpan="1"
        android:id="@+id/LLoneone">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/oneone"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:contentDescription="@string/gameboard"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:src="@drawable/tile" />

    </RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to stack layout elements on top of each other then you should use a `FrameLayout`.

Comment: Read the docs for FrameLayout first: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/FrameLayout.html

Most importantly this line: `Child views are drawn in a stack, with the most recently added child on top.`  Just be careful testing with different screensizes like it says if you go this route.